# How would I trap a user in a loop until given a valid input after printing an error message?

Tags: java, loops

I want to ask the user for an input and if it's not valid, I'll push out an error statement and ask the user to enter another input. How would I code a loop which would keep the user in the same input request after being given an error? Previous methods I've used were try and except in Python. What would be the equivalent in Java?

```html
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {
  //Setting Moves List
  enum Move {
    ROCK,
    PAPER,
    SCISSORS
  }
  //Initiate Scanner and accept user input
  public static String getUserMove() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String gesture = keyboard.nextLine();
    String userMove = gesture.toUpperCase();
    if (userMove.equals("ROCK") || userMove.equals("PAPER") || userMove.equals("SCISSORS")) {
      return userMove;
    } else {
      System.out.println("This is not a valid input." +
        "Please try again!");
      return "Invalid Input";
    }
  }
  //Get random input as CPU move
  public static String getAiMove() {
    String Ai;
    Random random = new Random();
    int input = random.nextInt(3);
    if (input == 1) {
      Ai = Move.ROCK.name();
    } else if (input == 2) {
      Ai = Move.PAPER.name();
    } else {
      Ai = Move.SCISSORS.name();
    }
    return Ai;
  }
  //Determine Winner Result
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Choose your move against the CPU:");
    System.out.println("ROCK, PAPER, OR  SCISSORS");

    String playerMove = getUserMove();
    System.out.println("You threw: " + playerMove);
    if (!playerMove.equals("Invalid Input")) {
      String cpuMove = getAiMove();
      System.out.println("Computer threw: " + cpuMove);
      if (playerMove.equals(cpuMove)) {
        System.out.println("Tie! Nobody Wins!");
      }
      // Player is Rock
      else if (playerMove.equals(Move.ROCK.name())) {
        if (cpuMove.equals(Move.PAPER.name())) {

          System.out.println("You Lost! \nPaper beats Rock!");
        } else {
          System.out.println("You Win! \nRock beats Scissors!");
        }
      }
      // Player is Paper
      else if (playerMove.equals(Move.PAPER.name())) {
        if (cpuMove.equals(Move.SCISSORS.name())) {
          System.out.println("You Lost! \nScissors beats Paper!");
        } else {
          System.out.println("You Win! \nPaper beats Rock!");
        }
      }
      // Player is Scissors
      else {
        if (cpuMove.equals(Move.ROCK.name())) {
          System.out.println("You Lost! \nPaper beats Rock!");
        } else {
          System.out.println("You Win! \nRock beats Scissors !");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: IIts as simple as `while(!isValid(input)){input = getInput();}`. substitute for your own input acquisiion and validity check. You really need to ask a more focused question. What *exactly* do you have a problem with? getting the input? checking it? writing a while-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your getUserMove method as below:-

```
public static String getUserMove() {
        boolean flag = true; 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String gesture = keyboard.nextLine();
       //loops until the user will not provide the desired input
        while (flag) {

            String userMove = gesture.toUpperCase();
            if (userMove.equals("ROCK") || userMove.equals("PAPER") || userMove.equals("SCISSORS")) {
                gesture = userMove;
                flag = false;// set flag to false once user will give valid input.
            } else {
                System.out.println("This is not a valid input." + "Please try again!");
                keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);// get input from user incase of invalid input.
                gesture = keyboard.nextLine();
            }
        }
        keyboard.close();// close scanner(to prevent memory leak)
        return gesture;
    }
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Question about **keyboard.close();**. Would you close the scanner every time you request user input or only when you don't need the scanner in your code anymore?

Comment: @MexicanPapi You are welcome. We close any resource only when we don't need it so that reference will not be there for that object and it will be collected by gc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your if statement in `getUserMove()`, you can try something like this, which will force the user to enter a valid `gesture`.

```java
  //Initiate Scanner and accept user input
  public static String getUserMove() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String gesture = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    while(!(userMove.equals("ROCK") || userMove.equals("PAPER") || userMove.equals("SCISSORS"))){
       System.out.println("This is not a valid input." + "Please try again!");
       gesture = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    }
    return gesture;
  }
```